# Replacing <li> image using javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the 3rd star in this list with an empty star based on a function. If the user has over 10 moves, the 3rd star should be replaced. After 14 moves, the 2nd star should also be replaced. I've tried the replaceChild Node but I can't get it working at all. Below is the UL list and as well as the function that I'm trying to associate it with. Is the replaceChild node the best method?

```
<div id="starRating">
  <ul id="stars" class="starlist" style="list-style-type:none">
     <li><img src="/images/filledstar.png" id="star1"> </li>
     <li><img src="/images/filledstar.png" id="star2"> </li>
     <li><img src="/images/filledstar.png" id="star3"> </li>
     <li><img src="/images/emptystar.png" id="star4"> </li>
   </ul>
</div>

function playerRating(moves) { //determines rating based on how many moves the player takes
  var rating = 3;
  if (moves > 10 && moves <= 13) {
    rating = 2;
  } else if (moves >= 14) {
    rating = 1;
  } else {
    rating = 3;
  } return rating;

  document.getElementById("rating").innerHTML = "Rating: "+ rating;
}
```

Comment: What should the stars be replaced with? Where is the empty star? And, what should trigger the function that replaces the stars?

Comment: There is supposed to be 3 filled stars, the last filled star will be replaced with the empty star as if their star rating is going down. The empty star is the last list item, it's labeled as "star4."

Comment: Yes, but what triggers the function to be run in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explain what triggers the function, but it would work something like this:

```js
// Get star references for empty and filled in
var filledStar1 = document.getElementById("filled1");
var filledStar2 = document.getElementById("filled2");
var filledStar3 = document.getElementById("filled3");
var emptyStar = document.getElementById("empty");

function playerRating(moves) { 
  var rating = 3;
  if (moves > 10 && moves <= 13) {
    filledStar3.src = emptyStar.src;
    rating = 2;
  } else if (moves >= 14) {
    filledStar2.src = emptyStar.src;
    filledStar3.src = emptyStar.src;
    rating = 1;
  } 
  return rating;

  document.getElementById("rating").textContent = "Rating: " + rating;
}

// Try these one at a time and you will see the ratings work
playerRating(9);
playerRating(11);
playerRating(14);
```

```css
img {width:50px;}
```

```html
<div id="starRating">
  <ul id="stars" class="starlist" style="list-style-type:none">
     <li><img src="http://www.bombmanual.com/manual/1/html/img/symbols/2-filledstar.png" id="filled1"> </li>
     <li><img src="http://www.bombmanual.com/manual/1/html/img/symbols/2-filledstar.png" id="filled2"> </li>
     <li><img src="http://www.bombmanual.com/manual/1/html/img/symbols/2-filledstar.png" id="filled3"> </li>
     <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/star-empty-m-128.png" id="empty"> </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<p id="rating"></p>
```